# Help understanding an equality

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can anyone explain to me the passage from the first to the second line? 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA0Yg.png

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
(X_{ij} - \overline{X}_j + \overline{X}_j - X_{lj})^2 &=& (X_{ij} - \overline{X}_j)^2 + (\overline{X}_j - X_{lj})^2 + 2 (X_{ij} - \overline{X}_j) (\overline{X}_j - X_{lj})\\
\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{l=1}^k (X_{ij} - \overline{X}_j + \overline{X}_j - X_{lj})^2 &=& \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{l=1}^k (X_{ij} - \overline{X}_j)^2 \\ &+& \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{l=1}^k (\overline{X}_j - X_{lj})^2 \\ &+& \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{l=1}^k 2 (X_{ij} - \overline{X}_j) (\overline{X}_j - X_{lj})\\
\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{l=1}^k (X_{ij} - \overline{X}_j)^2 &=& k \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^k (X_{ij} - \overline{X}_j)^2\\
\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{l=1}^k (\overline{X}_j - X_{lj})^2 &=& k \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{l=1}^k (\overline{X}_j - X_{lj})^2\\
&=& k \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^k (X_{ij} - \overline{X}_j)^2\\
\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{l=1}^k 2 (X_{ij} - \overline{X}_j) (\overline{X}_j - X_{lj}) &=& \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^k 2 (X_{ij} - \overline{X}_j) \sum_{l=1}^k (\overline{X}_j - X_{lj})\\
\sum_{l=1}^k (\overline{X}_j - X_{lj}) &=& k \overline{X}_j - \sum_{l=1}^k X_{lj} = 0\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you! it's clear now